# Trouble installing MAPP Stack as Root user in OSX

Tags: apache, terminal, mamp, osx-yosemite, bitnami

trying to install bitnami mappstack as root user on osx. I follow the direction on their help page to a 't', but I keep getting a 'command not found' error when I try to run the installbuilder.sh as a super user. I'm not very good with the terminal. What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
Andrews-iMac:volumes andrewpawlik$ sudo ./bitnami-mappstack-5.4.40-0-osx-x86_64-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh
Password:
sudo: ./bitnami-mappstack-5.4.40-0-osx-x86_64-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh: command not found
```

this is what their help page says

> To install the Stack as administrator you should click in the .dmg
>   file. Once the disk is mounted in your system, you can open a Terminal
>   and go to the folder:
>
> ```
> $ cd /Volumes/Your Bitnami Stack
> ```
>
> Then you can run the following command from a Terminal:
>
> ```
> $ sudo ./bitnami-application-version-osx-x86_64-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bitnami developer here. I've run it myself and worked fine for me. Please make sure you are inputing the right path. In my case i had to do run the following:

```
cd /Volumes/MAMP
sudo ./MAMP.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using the wrong directory path. I got it up and running now. Thanks for your response, and thanks for your amazing product!!